# Improve performance of game's update loop?

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code for a small game and at some point my code basically "updates" all my objects. For my player this involves checking if any movement key is pressed, then it should stop the "update" function for the player and move onto the next object. I have found that it goes extremely slow over the player "update" function.

Basically if I move my player my "update all" goes much faster than when it doesn't move at all. Is there a fast way to let my void "update" for my player go faster when no "if" criteria are met (as in, no movement keys pressed)?

EDIT: im using c++

Comment: There is absolutely no way to say how to improve the code without seeing it (and without even knowing which programming language you're talking about.)

Comment: It's possible that your event loop is waiting (blocking) on input. If there is no work to be done then this is the way to go, and the _slowness_ - if measured by a frame counter - is illusory. If there is work every frame then polling may be a better choice.

Comment: Sorry, i'm using c++, i didnt realise this forum was for multiple languages. I don't have acces to my code right now but for my player the update has four if statements, one to check for each arrow key. If i press an arrow and move it goes over the update really fast but if i dont it goes extremely slow. I would think that if none of the ifs are true it just skips over my void update and moves to the next object as it should, but apperently it doesnt work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to run a profiler, there're a lot available, choose one to your liking. It will show you how much time your program spends in every function. Once you know which precise lines of code are to blame, it's usually easy to fix it.